# How do you spell “mere” an English(England)word?

Tags: british-english

How do you spell “  mere” An English word meaning a well known walking path across the field or shortcut?

Comment: Tried googling this?

Answer (score 3):

> On Sunday a party of Congleton Group of the Ramblers enjoyed a 3 and a half mile walk in the Westlow [**Mere**](http://www.congletonramblers.org.uk/news/previouswalks) area. On a beautiful sunny day, 32 walkers set off from Rood Lane to join a footpath which was followed around the **mere** out to Grantswood Lane. The group then joined a woodland footpath along the North Eastern side of the **mere**. The sun was dappling through the golden leaves of the trees. While enjoying the beautiful setting a stop was made for refreshments. At this point it was pointed out that the group were unable to proceed to Havannah the planned route, as the main link path was barricaded off due to building work. The group continued around the **mere** to cut off through Daisy Bank to cross over the A34 to Hillfields.

[image: https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.99990/2015.99990.The-Oxford-English-Dictionary-Vol-6l-m#page/n891/mode/2up]

Image from *Oxford English Dictionary*, vol. 6 ([L-M](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.99990/2015.99990.The-Oxford-English-Dictionary-Vol-6l-m#page/n891/mode/2up)), c.1913

From *Lakeland Words: a collection of Dialect and Phrases, as used in Cumberland and Westmorland, with illustrative sentences in the Westmorland Dialect* :

[image: Mere meaning "mark"]

> [Mere](https://archive.org/stream/cu31924103992735#page/n119/mode/2up) -- An auld word for "mark"; land-mark [etc.]

Comment: You should give the source of the image you posted.

Comment: Give me a moment, and I'll add it. I already have the source given in the link for the picture.

Comment: Your first quotation clearly refers to the 'lake or pond' meaning; the second (which the current OED says is "difficult to distinguish from"  the  'boundary'  meaning)  is probably the closest to OPs request.

Comment: I understand. I decided to include the first reference because there is certainly a vague association of *mere* with unpaved roads or country lanes (among avid hikers). And I think the reason it is now so *difficult to distinguish* between the numerous historical definitions of *mere*, is probably because modern travel by automobile on paved roads has caused most people, who are accustomed to driving, to forget about the existence of the kinds of rural roads which are easier to navigate on foot.

Comment: Also if it's *difficult to distinguish* between those two meanings for *mere* then the meanings must be similar or perhaps interchangeable. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score -1):

I think the word you’re looking for is moor, an unplowed field.